# Webcam not responding on Windows XP

Tags: windows, webcam

I opened my webcam to record a video. It works well if I record for 1 - 2 hours. But it seems not responding when I record a video for 4 - 5 hours.

I tested recording on Windows 7 x64 and it worked, nothing happened. So I am just wondering is it because of Windows XP (32bit) having a problem with a long recording video from webcam?

Comment: Have you tried manually installing the drivers for it?

Comment: Yes I installed the drivers manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume so, but it is tough to point a finger at what it would possibly be. It could be a webcam driver bug, as Win7 uses a whole new 'windows driver model' which moves nearly all driver execution to user level instead of kernel level. Another possibility as there might be a memory leak in the code that sucks up RAM until it is full and causes a soft crash (stop recording). I would first try using a different application to record with your webcam than what your using, I know VLC has an open/save stream functionality, sometimes difficult to configure though.

Also, this sounds more like a SuperUser question.

Comment: A moderator can move this post to SuperUser, and chances are you will get more answers

Comment: thank you I will try to record a video by using different application.